# Exponential definite integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, mathematical-physics

Please can anybody tell the exact solution or the way to solve the integral of form 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2b^2(x^2+a^2)}dx$$

Comment: You would like to look at erf function

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2b^2(x^2+a^2)}dx =e^{-2b^2a^2}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2b^2x^2}dx$$ HINT : Look at the Gauss integral.

Comment: You can also relate it to the Gamma function.

Comment: good lord, have you even tried to search the site (or the web in general)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2b^2(x^2+a^2)}dx=e^{-2b^2a^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2b^2 x^2}dx=e^{-2b^2a^2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2b^2}}
$$
done using
$$
\int_{\mathbf R} e^{-\alpha x^2} {\rm dx}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

after taking out $e^{-2b^2a^2}$, substitute $\sqrt 2bx=t$.
this leaves us with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\text dt$ with some factor multiplied. Now we substitute $t = \sqrt { y}$ leaves us with $\Gamma({\frac 12})$.